# Android Drop Down List is Empty When using a String Array from values file

Tags: android

In my main activity in the onCreate method I am trying to add a string array from the R.array file to an array adapter.  When i go to launch the app the drop down box is empty.  If I manually create a String array via code the drop down is fully populated.  Here is the code below.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dateAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, R.array.reminderDays);
    dateAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);        
    dateRangeSpinner.setAdapter(dateAdapter);
    dateRangeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
```

Comment: I tried that but now the app immediatly crashes on startup.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> dateAdapter =ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, R.array.reminderDays);
```

This is working fine for me.

Comment: I tried that but now the app immediatly crashes on startup. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you povide stack trace from logcat?